# action failed:c: newasset_component$controller$doLibloaded['lightningUtilsLib' is undefined]

Tags: controller, component

I have a strange error when i try to search for client in the global search.

error action failed:c: newasset_component$controller$doLibloaded['lightningUtilsLib' is undefined]

Some help?

Thank you